# How To Set a date range in HTML5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am working on wedding website, in which I have a data countdown of wedding so but I don't get how to set a date that countdown show correct count down.

[image]

This is the code:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
          <ul class="countdown mt-xs-30" >
            <li> <span id="days-sub">days</span>
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#fff" data-fillcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)"  data-height="140" data-max="366" data-min="0" data-readonly="true" data-skin="tron"
                                    data-thickness="0.1" data-width="140" id="days">
            </li>
            <li> <span id="hours-sub">hours</span>
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#fff" data-fillcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" data-height="140" data-max="24" data-min="0" data-readonly="true" data-skin="tron"
                                    data-thickness="0.1" data-width="140" id="hours">
            </li>
            <li> <span id="mins-sub">minutes</span>
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#fff" data-fillcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" data-height="140" data-max="60" data-min="0" data-readonly="true" data-skin="tron" data-thickness="0.1" data-width="140" id="mins">
            </li>
            <li> <span id="secs-sub">seconds</span>
              <input class="knob" data-fgcolor="#fff" data-fillcolor="rgba(255,255,255,0.3)" data-height="140" data-max="60" data-min="0" data-readonly="true" data-skin="tron" data-thickness="0.1" data-width="140" id="secs">
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!-- launch countdown end --> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You should include the script that runs the countdown so we can work with that. Otherwise, for a full functioning demo, we would have to remake logic that you've already made.

Comment: May it can help you, http://jsfiddle.net/wz32sy7y/1/  ,    http://codepen.io/pik_at/pen/azeYRg

Comment: You Have to add see Js file to change date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This may it Help You..

```
  function happywedding_countdown() {
$(".countdown").countdown({
  date: "29 January 2016 00:00:00", // countdown target date settings
  format: "on"
  }, function() {
  });}
```

Comment: Ok i will try this and get back to you

Comment: it's been awhile. by the way it's working since you answer. thx.

Answer (score 0):

May it will helps you. :)

```js
var time = 10;
var initialOffset = '440';
var i = 1
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(i*(initialOffset/time)));
    $('h2').text(i);
    if (i == time) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    i++;  
}, 1000);
```

```css
.item {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.item h2 {
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 125px;
    width: 100%;
}

svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 440; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 440;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item html">
    <h2>0</h2>
    <svg width="160" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
      <title>Layer 1</title>
      <circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none"/>
     </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use *JQuery* plugin for that just you need to apply your style to this code and done.

You can use the best and suitable code is *JQ*. I accomplish it by using [keith wood countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

You need to just setup sort code for example I want to display countdown for coming new year timer:

**JQUERY**:

```
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<p>Counting down to 26 January <span id="year">2014</span>.</p>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
```

And countdown will working. For more detail you can check demo with multiple example from [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

**Reference**:
1. [GitHub](http://github.com/kbwood/countdown)
2. [jQuery Countdown](http://plugins.jquery.com/kbw.countdown/)

Hope this help!